# Not able to dispaly the ng-show/ng-if div while running the protractor test

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

I tried so many options but unable to display ng-show div while running the protractor test.

#### code

```
expect(element(by.className('.dispalyHiddenData')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

In this case getting always **expected false to be true** becasue of div exist in dom but not visible so **isPresent** is true. So kindly help me what is the way to display ng-show div while running the protractor test.

Comment: try to find the style property and check is its none or block or something else.

Comment: Hey Aniruddha thanks for the quick response and the scenario is little bit different actually the content where i want to write protractor is hidden while clicking on button the content is displaying so bydefault it is display none and after clicking on button the display is block.